# A shadow shows up whenever I try to present a previous view controller

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, viewcontroller

whenever I try to present a view controller a shadow appears right in front of my view controller, and I found out that I could dismiss it by pulling it down.

[image]

This is what the code inside the logoutButton looks like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
    
}
```

And this is what the handleLogout function looks like

```
@objc func handleLogout() {
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
    do {
        try firebaseAuth.signOut()
    } catch let signOutError as NSError {
        print("Error", signOutError)
    }
    
    let loginController = LoginViewController()
    present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Does anybody know how to tackle this problem?

I wonder if this code which I wrote really makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the shadow you are seeing is your actual LoginViewController

Try

```
let loginController = LoginViewController()
loginController.view.backgroundColor = .blue
present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If your shadow turns blue you know that it's presenting a loginViewController but it appears to be empty and your problem lies there.